# Multiple edit forms based on a template form

Tags: forms, delphi, templates

I'm working upon a small-scale enterprise database application. It works with such business objects as Vendors, Device types, Devices, Suppliers, Invoices, Departments, Employees etc., so I need to let users view and edit data from all these tables.

My first approach was to create a pair of forms for each type of business object:

1. a table to view and select an object
2. an editing form for this type of object

But now I find it hard to maintain all these forms, because e.g. if I want to change the look of all view forms, of course I have to edit each one of them.
So I want to replace all my view forms with a single one "template" form and to call it with some kind of parameters. The problem is, I don't know the right approach to perform it. Maybe there could be some example in some book or somewhere else?

Comment: See [Visual Form Inheritance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R9ODPa6794), or [Visual Form Inheritance](http://delphi.about.com/od/oopindelphi/a/delphi_oop4.htm), or...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way is by using [Visual Form Inheritance](http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+II+Delphi+Object-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+8+The+Architecture+of+Delphi+Applications/Visual+Form+Inheritance/) .
Actually we use this kind of programming a lot, it keeps maintenance pretty simple.  Stick your base functionality in the parent form, and specific behaviour in the child forms.